# Incorrect conversion from Raw RGB Depth image to gray

Tags: python, c++, image, opencv, depth

I am working with a simulation in Python equipped with a depth sensor. The visualization it's done in C++. The sensor gives me the following image that I need to convert to gray.

[image: Raw Depth]

For the conversion, I have the next formula:

```
normalized = (R + G * 256 + B * 256 * 256) / (256 * 256 * 256 - 1)
in_meters = 1000 * normalized
```

For converting the image to gray in C++, I've written the following code:

```
cv::Mat ConvertRawToDepth(cv::Mat raw_image)
{
    // raw_image.type() => CV_8UC3

    // Extend raw image to 2 bytes per pixel
    cv::Mat raw_extended = cv::Mat::Mat(raw_image.rows, raw_image.cols, CV_16UC3, raw_image.data);

    // Split into channels
    std::vector<cv::Mat> raw_ch(3);
    cv::split(raw_image, raw_ch); // B, G, R

    // Create and calculate 1 channel gray image of depth based on the formula
    cv::Mat depth_gray = cv::Mat::zeros(raw_ch[0].rows, raw_ch[0].cols, CV_32FC1);
    depth_gray = 1000.0 * (raw_ch[2] + raw_ch[1] * 256 + raw_ch[0] * 65536) / (16777215.0);

    // Create final BGR image
    cv::Mat depth_3d;
    cv::cvtColor(depth_gray, depth_3d, cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGR);

    return depth_3d;
}
```

Achieving the next result:

[image: Cpp Depth]

If I do the conversion in python, I can simply write:

```
def convert_raw_to_depth(raw_image):
    raw_image = raw_image[:, :, :3]
    raw_image = raw_image.astype(np.float32)
    
    # Apply (R + G * 256 + B * 256 * 256) / (256 * 256 * 256 - 1).
    depth = np.dot(raw_image, [65536.0, 256.0, 1.0])
    depth /= 16777215.0  # (256.0 * 256.0 * 256.0 - 1.0)
    depth *= 1000
    
    return depth
```

Achieving the next result:

[image]

It's clear that in python it's done better, but the formula is the same, the image is the same, then why is it a difference and how can I rewrite the code in C++ to give me similar results as in Python?

Comment: which pixel format it `raw_image`? If it isnt 16 bit per channel, your `CV_16UC3` doesnt make much sense. If it is 16 bit per channel, your multiplications by 256 and 256 x 256 doesnt make much sense.

Comment: @Micka The comment says `raw_image.type() => CV_8UC3`

Comment: @Micka we saw that before. it's splitting the 24 bits of depth into three bytes, and putting each into a color channel. the given equation gives that away.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz but that doesn't make much sense with the CV_16UC3 code. If input was 16uc3 the I would expect 2^0, 2^16 and 2^32 as multipliers.

Comment: I have no idea what OP was thinking there with the 16UC3. makes no sense. OP doesn't necessarily know what they're doing. bad to assume in general. `raw_extended` is also never used, so it's irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are dealing with `np.float32` array in Python while `CV_8UC3` array in C++.

Try converting to `CV_32FC3` before calculation.

```cpp
    // Convert to float and split into channels
    cv::Mat raw_image_float;
    raw_image.convertTo(raw_image_float, CV_32FC3);
    std::vector<cv::Mat> raw_ch(3);
    cv::split(raw_image_float, raw_ch); // B, G, R
```

Comment: The "depth_gray " matrix it's of CV_32FC1 type, and when the computation it's done, I expect for the result to be float and saved correctly.
I've tested this and it works just as in python!

Thank you!